# How to parse complex logical operations in java?

Tags: java, parsing, logical-operators

Is there any way to parse strings which include logical `and`/`or` operators and get result as true or false in java? For example

```
    (1 OR 0 AND 1 AND 0 OR(0 AND 0))
```

I couldn't find any library. Actually I have some ideas but they are so complex. Maybe some easier way?

Comment: You could use ant and define your own grammar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java. But you may have to modify your input expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use already mentioned script engine:

```
String expression = "(1 || 0 && 1 && 0 ||(0 && 0))";
Object result = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval(expression);
System.out.println(result);
```

or spring expression language:

```
String data = "(true OR false AND true AND false OR(false AND false))";
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(data);
result = exp.getValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

Please note, that in both cases there was needed to modify original expression by replacing eighter lofical operators or logical constants.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!